# What is the work of self destruct in a contract?

Tags: attacks, solidity

How it can be used for handling force sending of ether to a contract without triggering fallback function ?

Answer (score 1):

The `selfdestruct` opcode simply doesn't create a call to the address, it just adds the `selfdestruct`ing contract's balance to the address it specifies.

Answer (score 0):

When the smart contract at that address performs the selfdestruct it removes smart contract from the blockchain.
selfdestruct sends all remaining Ether stored in the contract to a designated address.

here is an example to demonstrate a concept. Not to be used directly in production.

```
    contract Test {
    uint public y;
    uint256 public bal;
    address payable public me;
    // This function is called for all messages sent to
    // this contract, except plain Ether transfers
    // Any call with non-empty calldata to this contract will execute
    // the fallback function (even if Ether is sent along with the call).
    fallback() external payable { 
        y = msg.value; 
        bal = address(this).balance;
    }

    // This function is called for plain Ether transfers, i.e.
    // for every call with empty calldata.
    receive() external payable { 
        y = msg.value; 
        bal = address(this).balance;
    }

    // Note: It just to test concept. not something advisable to do in 
    //production.
    // call to close function will remove code and storage from the state.
    // but it is still part of the history of the blockchain and probably 
    // retained by most Ethereum nodes 
    // if you sends Ether to removed contracts, the Ether is forever lost
    function close() public {
     me = payable(msg.sender);
    selfdestruct(me);
    } 
}
```

Comment: what language is this?